# concat value to display result from resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources

I have a value code and want to concat to a string "result" and look in the resource file

```
Eval("code")
```

so it would be result101

```
<asp:Literal Text='<%$ Resources:ResultList, result + Eval("code")%>' runat="server"/>
```

what is the right syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, in case anyone needs: <%# GetGlobalResourceObject("ResultList", "result" + Eval("code").ToString())%>